# What can be the reason for FCM token not working?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had accidentally deleted FCM token and now with the new token (it looks like its the same one returned by SDK) I can not send any messages.
The error I get is...

`Error: The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons. See the error documentation for more details. Remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages.`

Any idea how to refresh the FCM token?

**Update:**

This gets executed on every page load

```
messaging
        .requestPermission()
        .then(() => {
            return messaging.getToken()
        })
        .then((token) => {
            if(token){
                return firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set({
                    notificationToken: token
                }, {merge: true})
            }
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
            console.error(e, 'Unable to get token')
        })
```

Comment: No. It's a web app. I request token on every page refresh and when the token is received, I save it. So if it already existed, it would overwrite.

So when I accidentally deleted the token, I went to developer console of chrome and removed the app from Notifications so app asks me for permissions again. It did ask and that latest token was saved to firestore. But when I try to send a message, it throws an error. I think, even after giving permissions again, I got the same token I had earlier. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I went to developer console of chrome and removed the app from Notifications so app asks me for permissions again.

Sounds like this issue: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/210

Can you try with version 4.13?

Answer (score 0):

```
String fcmToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Keep fcm token in database. When user login to the app send fcm token value with username and password.